# In Perforce how to add a file to existing shelve from another user?

Tags: perforce

I have a shelve (S) created by another team member and it has files a.txt and b.txt. I want to add another file which I have edited , c.txt, to the same shelve S. Is that possible in perforce ?

If I edit or reopen the c.txt in changelist S, then I get message that S belongs to other client (other team member).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** you probably do not want to be using shelves for this.  You probably want to be using a branch and submitting to it.  What you're doing is more difficult than a standard Perforce workflow and feels like an attempt to translate a workflow from some other tool into Perforce using concepts that don't map perfectly.  I recommend not doing this and maybe describing your overall use case to an experienced Perforce user who can tell you the more idiomatic way of doing it in Perforce.  :)

That said: see this article on changing ownership of a pending change.
https://community.perforce.com/s/article/2531
Note that a shelved changelist is really just a pending changelist with shelved revisions attached, and is generally scoped to a single user, but it *can* be transferred between users via that process.

Good luck!